# Azure web service to Azure web service authenticated requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-authentication

I have an Azure-based .NET Core Web API application that I want to communicate with an Azure-based MVC5 application.  The MVC5 application requires its clients to have a credential in our Azure AD instance.  We connect to this app with our SSO Azure AD credentials.

The .NET Core app does *not* authenticate against Azure; there's no credential pass-through possible for its consumers.  BUT... it's hosted in the same Azure instance, so it seems like I should be able to send an authenticated request from the web api to the MVC app with relative ease.

The documentation on this is quite confusing though.  There's talk about x.509 certs (this really doesn't seem necessary), OAuth 2.0 grants and flows (I may not be able to get around that, I don't know)... but is there some simple, relatively "brainless" way to have the one service talk securely with the other without building some kind of complicated scaffolding and/or configuration? I'm kinda hoping there's a way to just instantiate a `HttpClient` or `WebRequest`, call some method to get the proper Authorization header (or maybe cookie?), and send my request on its merry way... but if it exists, it remains elusive to me.

Any elucidation on this would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: MSI is meant to be the way to do this https://jpd.ms/using-azure-managed-service-identities-with-your-apps-b979564ddf4 ... however that is also not very clear and I've only got it working in limited circumstances. The idea is you generate a MSI against whatever your .NET core app is running in (Azure Web App?) and you give that MSI access to your MVC5 app. If you get it working, please write it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of depends.  First, to be clear, you are trying to call an action in the MVC app from the API app?  This seems a little odd (more often, a MVC front-end might need to call the api).  Regardless, it should still be the same.

Question: Do you want you api app to always call the MVC app as "itself"?  So, your api app would have an identity that is authorized to call an action on your MVC app?  If so, this is exactly what the OAuth Client Credentials flow is for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service

With this flow, you create an Azure AD application registration that represents your API app.  Then, at runtime, your API app uses its client id and client secret to acquire a token it can use to call the MVC app (typically passed as a bearer token in the Authorization header).  Part of what you can do with the app registration is give it delegated access to your MVC app, but you can also manage which "clients" you want to allow access in your MVC app.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I agree it's odd; this is a "new" application talking to a "legacy" application that we haven't gotten around to rebuilding yet.  I'll look into the document you linked to, hopefully there's enough there to piece together what I need to do.  Thanks!